# Fairly complicated partial derivative

Tags: statistics, partial-derivative

I have a stats assignment, that requires the use of non linear regression - this I am fine with in principle, however I can't get the initial $X$ matrix, because I don't understand partial derivatives. All the examples I have found are either very simple, or don't explain why things are the way they are, or both.

So, this is the equation:
$$y_i = \frac{r_1^*x_i^2+x_i(1-x_i)}{r_1^*x_i^2+2x_i(1-x_i) + r_2^*(1-x_i)^2}+\mathcal{E}_i$$

I need to know the derivative with relation to $r_1^*$ and $r_2^*$. I would love to know both the equation of how to get it (with an explanation) as well as the actual values where:
$r_1^* = 0.4$
$r_2^* = 0.6$

for each of these four $x_i$'s:

```
0.2145
0.6074
0.7831
0.8976
```

Like I said above, an explanation, the equation and the answers would be great, as I am totally stumped!

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your question to use $\LaTeX$.  This can be a great substitute for pasting in a picture (and has no lower rep limit!).  For help with formatting in the future, please see [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Question: Do you understand normal derivatives, and just have problems with partials, or do you not understand derivatives at all?

Comment: @anorton, I understand basic derivatives - sort of, i.e I know x^3 = 3x, and I did have to do one or two more complicated ones involving fractions of this. But it wasnt so much understanding as "this is the rule - you dont need to know why". Thanks for editing my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  The derivative of $x^3$ is $3x^2$, not $3x$.  If you know the quotient and product rules it is mechanical.  I don't have much intuition about this, either.  For the partial with respect to $r_1^*$ you just need to remember that *everything else* is a constant.  So the partial of the numerator with respect to $r_2^*$ is zero-it is a constant.

Added:  because the quotient rule says $\frac {\partial \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}}{\partial x}=\frac {g(x)\frac{\partial {f(x)}}{\partial x}-f(x)\frac{\partial {g(x)}}{\partial x}}{(g(x))^2}$ we have

$\frac {\partial y_i}{\partial r_2^*} = \frac{-(r_1^*x_i^2+x_i(1-x_i))(1-x_i)^2}{(r_1^*x_i^2+2x_i(1-x_i) + r_2^*(1-x_i)^2)^2}$

Comment: Note: I knew that about the 3x part - tired eyes :( but thanks for pointing it out. I had thought that the numerator was 0 on one of my initial attempts, however had disregarded that because, if the numerator is 0, how can the result be anything other than 0 (0/anything, etc). I am now looking at the khan academy tutorials on quotient and product rules, and am getting closer to finding the solution...I think!

Comment: Thank you SO much. Whats interesting is that I tried this as a solution last night, but when the first iteration resulted in negative changes in point estimates for r1 and r2, but the second iteration resulted in positive changes, I decided I must have made a mistake - however as my assignent said after 4 iterations, the values converged. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want just fit a nonlinear curve, use a package.

Download the R statistical program in www.r-project.org/cran. It is free!

Then define the response variable
y<-c(y1,y2,y3,...,yn)

define the explanatory variable
x<-c(x1,x2,x3,...,xn)

Nonlinear functions are fitted with

mod<-nls(y~formula,start=c(r1=1.0,r2=5))

in formula you must specify the model, example: r1*exp(x*r2)

start is the vector with initial guesses for the parameter values: you must to choice appropriate values

In order to see the estimated coefficients, make
summary(mod)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm interested in getting the derivative of the above function, the end goal is to perform non linear regression, however that part I can (and want to) do by hand, for this reason: its on an assignment now, in a weeks time it will be on an exam.